# how to count columns for each window faster than perl while loop

Tags: perl, awk

I would like to count columns for the matching windows. I tried awk but it's too slow.

For example, I have the following two windows

```
chr1-100-1000
chr1-1500-3000
```

For these 2 windows I found the following matches and would like to count the 6th column based on whether the last column is 1 or 0.

```
chr1 100 1000 chr1 200 0 1 0
chr1 100 1000 chr1 500 0 4 0
chr1 100 1000 chr1 700 0 6 1
chr1 1500 3000 chr1 2000 0 9 1
chr1 1500 3000 chr1 2000 0 1 0
```

My desired results will be

```
chr1 100 1000 6/11
chr1 1500 3000 9/10
```

I tried doing this with a while loop in perl, but since I have millions of entries it is very slow. Here is what I tried

```
while (my $line = <IN>){
    chomp $line;
    my ($chrV,$start,$end) = split("-",$line);

    my $total_mcTotal = `awk '{if (\$2 == $start && \$3 == $end) print \$8}' chr$chr\_intersect_temp | awk \'{sumT+=\$1} END {print sumT}\'`;
    chomp $total_mcTotal;

    `awk '{if (\$2 == $start && \$3 == $end) print \$7}' chr$chr\_intersect_Meth_temp > temp_$chr`;
    my $total_mcCount = `awk \'{sum+=\$1} END {print sum}\' temp_$chr`;
    chomp $total_mcCount;
```

Is there a faster solution?

Comment: If you have a working solution in awk, why don't you also post that so we can see what you tried.

Comment: Where are the windows specified - as parameters or in a file? Which part of the matches you have found matches? And what does it match with? If you want the benefits of computer scientists helping you, you will need to explain in computing, not bio-informatics, terms what you want.

Comment: Please post the *real* Perl program that you tried. What you show doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can guarantee the data is ordered, this could be simplified:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @keys;
my %vals;

while (<DATA>) {
    s{(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)\s+}{} or warn("No key at line $.: $_") and next;
    my $key = $1;
    my @data = split;
    if (!$vals{$key}) {
        push @keys, $key;
        $vals{$key} = {n => 0, d => 0}; # Ensure n gets initialized
    }
    $vals{$key}{d} += $data[3];
    $vals{$key}{n} += $data[3] if $data[4];
}

for (@keys) {
    # printf "%s %d/%d\n", $_, $vals{$_}{n}, $vals{$_}{d};
    my $fraction = $vals{$_}{d}
        ? sprintf("%.02f", $vals{$_}{n}/$vals{$_}{d})
        : 'NaN';
    print "$_ $fraction\n";
}

__DATA__
chr1 100 1000 chr1 200 0 1 0
chr1 100 1000 chr1 500 0 4 0
chr1 100 1000 chr1 700 0 6 1
chr1 1500 3000 chr1 2000 0 9 1
chr1 1500 3000 chr1 2000 0 1 0
```

Outputs:

```
chr1 100 1000 6/11
chr1 1500 3000 9/10
```

**Edit**

Or not worrying about the specific spacing for the key:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    my @data = split;
    my $key = join ' ', @data[0..2];
    push @keys, $key if !$vals{$key};
    $vals{$key}{d} += $data[6];
    $vals{$key}{n} += $data[6] if $data[7];
}
```

Comment: Hi Miller, thanks. The data is sorted. can you also please explain me what it does.

Comment: This pulls the key from each line, `chr 100 1000` or `chr 1500 3000` for these lines, and then sums the data from the 7th column (index 3 after adjusting for columns the key).  It then prints the accumulated data at the very end.

Comment: when you are printhing the last column, how can i actually do the dividing? instead of 6/11, print 0.54?

Comment: i am almost there. In my actual data there are 17 columns and it is tab delimited. I am now trying to understand what does "s/(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)" do. The numbers i would like to add is col 16 and col 17

Comment: I didn't have to use a regular expression to pull out the key.  I also could've just relied on the `split` if we didn't care about the spacing in the key.  I've provided an edit that shows this simplified parsing method.  Also, if you just want to print the fraction as a decimal, you could use this: `printf "%s %.02f\n", $_, $vals{$_}{n} / $vals{$_}{d};`

Comment: all sorted except some where the last column is all zero. THen it complaints about division by zero. I tried to insert an if condition if($vals{$_} == 0){ skip it} else{ ...} but it does not recognize the if loop. What am i missing?

Comment: To handle the divide by 0 cases, just check to see if the denominator is 0 before printing.  Edited my answer to show that.

Comment: I keep getting the 'Use of uninitialized value in division (/)' message and could not figure out how to solve this. I tried your solution and modified it mysels a bit but still no luck. do you know why is this happening?

Comment: the problem is with this line $vals{$key}{n} += $data[6] if $data[7];. If there is a window whose 7th column are all zeros, $vals{$key}{n} is not created. But I still want to keep it and record the final value as 0. But the codes doesnt recognize it and says it is not initialized

Comment: Yes, that is true.  So all you need to do is initialize it before printing it since there's a possibility that it won't be.  That's why my original solution used `printf` to output that value: `printf "%d", $vals{$_}{n};`, because even if that is undefined, printf will treat it like 0 and won't give a warning.  To defensively initialize it, just use `$vals{$_}{n} ||= 0;` or `$vals{$_}{n} += 0;`.  Either would work.

Comment: There, I made an edit to defensively initializes n whenever a new key is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code by using awk only.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{str=$1 FS $2 FS $3;p[str FS $NF]+=$(NF-1);next}
{ str=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3;
  print str,p[str OFS "1"] "/" p[str OFS "1"]+p[str OFS "0"]
}' file2 FS="-" file1

chr1 100 1000 6/11
chr1 1500 3000 9/10
```

#### explanation

- `str=$1 FS $2 FS $3;p[str FS $NF]+=$(NF-1)` set 4D array and sum the value on $(NF-1)